# User is not available in request with NestJS passport strategy (other than documentation exemples)

Tags: passport.js, nestjs

I'm trying to implement a passport strategy (passport-headerapikey), I was able to make it work and I can secure my routes.
But the request is empty and cannot access the logged in user ?

```
import { HeaderAPIKeyStrategy } from "passport-headerapikey";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { CompanyService } from "../../companies/companies.service";

@Injectable()
export class ApiKeyStrategy extends PassportStrategy(HeaderAPIKeyStrategy, "api-key") {
  constructor(private readonly companyService: CompanyService) {
    super(
      {
        header: "Authorization",
        prefix: "Api-Key "
      },
      true,
      async (apiKey, done) => {
        return this.validate(apiKey, done);
      }
    );
  }

  public async validate(apiKey: string, done: (error: Error, data) => {}) {
    const company = await this.companyService.findByApiKey(apiKey);
    if (company === null) {
      throw new NotFoundException("Company not found");
    }
    return company;
  }
}


@UseGuards(AuthGuard("api-key"))
export class CompaniesController {
  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {}
  @Get()
  @ApiOperation({ title: "Get company information" })
  public getCompany(@Request() req) {
    // here request is empty, so i cannot access the user..
    console.log("request", req);
    return [];
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you were to remove the guard, is the `req` object still empty?

Comment: yes still empty

Comment: That seems like something is wrong with the api endpoint. There are no erros when starting the server? Any chance you can share logs or the application code in a git repo?

Comment: I cannot share, but other routes in our application the request object is not empty, i'm trying to find what is wrong with this route only.

Comment: My only thoughts are middleware misfiring, or importing the wrong `Request`. Otherwise the code looks fine and should be working as expected

Comment: Ok i found it, i already have a CompaniesController and a getCompany method (in another module).... so when i changed the method name getCompanyXXXX it is working. wtf..

Answer (score 1):

To access the logged user, you can inject the object in the request. To do that, in your `ApiKeyStrategy` constructor, change the third parameter to something like this:

```
async (apiKey, verified, req) => {
  const user = await this.findUser(apiKey);
  // inject the user in the request
  req.user = user || null;
  return verified(null, user || false);
}
```

Now, you can access the logged user:

```
getCompany(@Request() req) {
  console.log(req.user);
}
```

I hope that could help you.

Answer (score 0):

As show in the documentation you should do some works to get the current user : here the [documetation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication)

First of all in the app.module make sure that the context is set :

```
context: ({ req }) =>  ({ req })
```

Then you can add this in the controller/resolver, this example use the Gql (GraphQL):

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
     const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
     return ctx.getContext().req.user;
  },
);
```

if this one doesnt work for you try this one instead :

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    const request  = ctx.getContext();
    request.body = ctx.getArgs();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify your `validate` method like so:

```
public async validate(apiKey: string, done: (error: Error, data) => {}) {
    const company = await this.companyService.findByApiKey(apiKey);
    if (company === null) {
      return done(new NotFoundException("Company not found"), null);
    }
    return done(null, company);
  }
```

Comment: [Please edit your answer so that it is in English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/4502035)